# SQL Server: sending parameter to function - parameter is name of table

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I'd like to create function that gives me back numbers of rows depends on parameter which is name of table. Is it possible ? If yes, how to change the code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction ( @sometable NVARCHAR(50) )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN SELECT COUNT(*) N_ROWS FROM @sometable
```

Thank you for answer.

Comment: I think you will need to use dynamic SQL here. See https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/ for more information.

Comment: Thank you for link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `dynamic query` for this like

```
declare @sql nvarchar(250);
set @sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS N_ROWS FROM ' + @sometable;
exec(@sql);
```

But again, you are trying to create a `FUNCTION` and you can't have a dynamic query in function. You may want to convert that to a `stored procedure`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Rahul for hint. 
 
I did like that:
 .... 
BEGIN 
          DECLARE @ret INT
          DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
 
          SET @sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) N_ROWS FROM ' + @sometable 
          EXEC sp_executesql @ret = @sql    
          RETURN @ret
     END;

Answer (score 0):

you can't have a dynamic query in function. You may want to convert that to a stored procedure

CREATE PROC PROC_Name
(
  @sometable NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(200)
     SET @Name = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS N_ROWS FROM ' + @sometable;
     EXEC (@Name)
END